How to expose a local network docker container web server to DynDNS requests from the internet with DS lite
How to expose a local network docker container web server to DynDNS requests from the internet
Off topic
Evaluated 31 mins ago |
I am so lost :-(
I am pretty sure that what I want to achieve has been done a million times, but I can't figure it out.
I have a local network docker container with a webserver (in the end it will be a traefik handling multiple services, but for debugging I reduced it to a simple httpd) listining on port 80. The host machine has a ipv4 address from within 192.168.1.X and a public ipv6 address (2a02:810d: ...) I setup duckdns to route a subdomain to that public ipv6 address.
My router is setup to allow packets to that ip on ports 80 and 443.
I do not have a static ipv4 publich address I do have DS lite with a static ipv6 praefix and a /64 subnet on the router
I can reach one of my Wifi repeaters just fine with the above setup (testing with https://ready.chair6.net/ which at least reports whether port 80 responds). But I can't get the httpd to respond for the love of god.
I tried:
assigning docker a subnet (/80) for the public ipv6 range (using /etc/docker/daemon.json) and allowing the main router to have another router inside its subnet
trying multiple setups for networks inside docker
httpd is accessible from the local network with the ipv6 public address.
As the main router firewall opens fine (tested above) my guess is that something in the docker hosts firewall prevents packages to arrive at the container. But let's say iptables and I are not great friends :-D
Any ideas and help is welcome.
Thank you so much Steven

It seems to be a problem with me host. I repurposed a rpi to host my application with traefik and it works like a charm.

No answer except probably a badly configured main host. It works on a separate machine.
